# SpringOauth Token using X509

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am working on a project where, two types of clients needs authentication token.
- IOT Devices
- Web Clients

Web clients follow typical suite, while IOT devices present cetificate for authentication, how can i use that with AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter to generate TOKEN, besides formlogin route.

```
   MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
   params.add("grant_type", "password");
   this.mockMvc.perform(post("/oauth/token")
            .params(params)
            .with(httpBasic("clientID","clientSecret"))
            //.with(x509("client.crt"))
            .accept("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(log());
```

when

```
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//@Autowired
//private X509CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
     http
     .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").fullyAuthenticated()
     .and()
        .x509()
     .and()
        .formLogin()

     .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
     .and()
         .csrf().disable();
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Problem is if not Authorisation Server Web Security Works fine, as soon as i enable

```
  @EnableAuthorizationServer
  @Configuration
  public class AuthorisationServerConfiguration extends 
  AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
```

it starts throwing

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad credentials"}

I need to extract username password from certificate before processing token request

Comment: Following test works MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
     params.add("grant_type", "password");
     params.add("username", "user");
     params.add("password", "password");
     params.add("scope", "read");
     
    
  this.mockMvc.perform(post("/oauth/token")
          .params(params)
          .with(httpBasic("miurasystems","secret"))
          .accept("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
          .andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(log());

Comment: And i kind of know whats happening AbstractTokenGranter.grant expects TokenRequest to be populated with username and password which need to be injected by some filter upstream extracting from x59 certificate

Comment: Oh, your are using password grant and your are calling token endpoint, then your `WebSecurity` is not used. By default token endpoint is using HTTP basic. You could change it in your `AuthorisationServerConfiguration` class.

Comment: Cant seem to find how